# Images in custom /media path redirect some images to get.php when accessed via CloudFront CDN

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, cloudfront-cdn

I have some images stored in `media/email/images/`. I accessed the images via CDN and all loaded as they should. Afterwards I mistakenly deleted a few images and eventually the CDN URL for the missing images begin redirecting to Magento's get.php.

I restored the missing images to the directory yet these particular files continue to redirect. I can access the file at ***www.site.com***/media/email/images/missingimage.jpg but not at ***cdn.site.com***/media/email/images/missingimage.jpg - it redirects to `www.site.com/get.php`.

I have tried the following CloudFront invalidation:

- /media/email/images*
- /media/email/images/image1.jpg
- /media/email/images/image2.jpg
- /media/email/images/image3.jpg
- media/email/images/image1.jpg
- media/email/images/image2.jpg
- media/email/images/image3.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as usual the second you describe an issue everything clicks. For anyone facing the same issue with redirects remember that many browsers cache redirects. After making these changes clear your own browser cache.

### What resolved my issue?

Waiting a minute or two after the invalidation completed to ensure everything was absolutely finished and then clearing my browser cache.